# Connection refused when adding shard in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, sharding

I followed the [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sharded-cluster-in-mongodb-using-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) to create a basic sharded cluster in MongoDB with 1 query router,1 config server and 2 shards without replication on the Virtual box in Ubuntu 16.04. I have successfully established the connection between Query Router and Config server according to the tutorial provided but I am getting the error

```
   { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Connection refused", "code" : 6 }
```

when I run **sh.addShard("ip:port")**. Can someone point what wrong I have been doing?
PS: I have bindIP as 0.0.0.0 on all my nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error was quite trivial which I figured out by using the tool nmap

```
    sudo nmap -p 27017 IP_of_the_shard_node
```

I figured out that the port 27017 was closed to connections.I realised that the mongod service was not running. Therefore a simple

```
   sudo systemctl start mongod
```

on shard node would solve the problem.